# Trying to understand bit ram address

Tags: c, embedded, bit, ram, pic

I'm trying to understand this piece of code to address bits:

```
/*  GPIO bits   */
static bit  GP5 @ (unsigned)&GPIO*8+5;
static bit  GP4 @ (unsigned)&GPIO*8+4;
static bit  GP3 @ (unsigned)&GPIO*8+3;
static bit  GP2 @ (unsigned)&GPIO*8+2;
static bit  GP1 @ (unsigned)&GPIO*8+1;
static bit  GP0 @ (unsigned)&GPIO*8+0;
```

The GPIO is defined in this way:

```
static volatile unsigned char   GPIO    @ 0x06;
```

Why GPIO address is multiplied by 8 and then added by the number of the bit? What the result of this macro and how can I address the bit?

The code above is for XC8 compiler for PIC Microcontrollers. Atmel uses the same when they use the macro **IOPORT_CREATE_PIN**. This macro is defined as below:

```
#define IOPORT_CREATE_PIN(port, pin)    ((IOPORT_##port)*8 + (pin))
```

Comment: look at the documentation for the part, it should be pretty obvious. Examine the size of the I/O registers for reading a port and/or pin within a port.  That should explain the address calculation.  I would not expect this to be consistent among vendors, esp from microchip to atmel, that is simply a coincidence in this one case. The compiler is interesting, but the more important detail we need is the part number.  Your question is extremely specific to that part or family.

Comment: This syntax is not C so much as it is XC8, you may want to adjust the tags accordingly.

Comment: @BrianCain, this sintax can be explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955856/sign-in-c-variable-declaration

Comment: @DanielGrillo, I understand the syntax, but it's not legal C, so you may find that SO frowns on the use of the 'C' tag for stuff that's not *quite* C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Why GPIO address is multiplied by 8 and then added by the number of the bit? What the result of this macro and how can I address the bit?"

It's the count of bits from the lowest address: 8 bits per byte plus offset into the byte.

You can address the bit by that name, e.g., `GP3 = 1;`. The compiler knows it is a single bit. As pointed out, this is a particular compiler extension for the PIC.

Answer (score 1):

Because each special function register has 8 bits (depends on the microcontroller). The address of `GP0` is `0x06*8+0 = 0x30`. Ways to address a bit also depends on the microcontroller. Sorry, I don't familiar with PIC. You may figure it out on your own.

[image]

Comment: This is the problem. There's nothing saying about reference a bit neither PIC nor AVR.

Comment: @DanielGrillo Since GPx(e.g. GP0) has been defined, it can be addressed directly, I think. Like this: `GP0 = 1;  // set GP0`

Comment: But why it is accessed by the address 0x30 instead of 0x06?

Comment: @DanielGrillo It is not a byte address. The PIC compiler also employs bit addresses.