# Is this valid code? extern marked with @ and address, from PIC microcontroller libraries

Tags: c, syntax, clang, pic, pic18

I used clang to perform some analysis on my code for a PIC18 microcontroller. It gets lots of errors and which seem to be caused by lines in the headers like this.

```
extern volatile unsigned char ANSELA @ 0xF38;
```

I understand what this is doing, mapping a symbol to a register on the chip, however is this standard C or is this a microchip only extension for their compilers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however is this standard C or is this a microchip only extension for their compilers?

It is not Standard C but it is a common extension used by some C embedded compilers.

See my answer here on this specific topic:

[@ sign in C variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955856/sign-in-c-variable-declaration)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well actually I starting answering when I noticed I may have already answered a similar question. Must be a dup.

Comment: I do that too -- answer a question and then realize I've answered something very similar before, so it must be a dup.